# TS : How to create a type factory using a string to generate the keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I am trying to create a way to easily generate a type that defines a multitude of key values association with a specific name pattern in the keys.

I have a specific type that is very repetitive, as for any metrics (working on analytics), I have a 4 keys associated.

For example, for the `firstPageVisible` metric, I will have `firstPageVisibleMetrics`, `firstPageVisibleCount`, `firstPageVisibleMetricsPerDevices`, `firstPageVisibleCountPerDevices`.

But as I have many metrics, I would like to have some sort of factory to make is easier to read.

I was imagining something like :

```js
type DetailedMetric<Type> = (
    name: string,
) => {
    [`${name}Metrics`]?: Type;
    [`${name}Count`]?: number;
    [`${name}MetricsPerDevices`]?: PerDeviceData<Type>;
    [`${name}CountPerDevices`]?: PerDeviceData<number>;
};
```

But I am having the error : `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.`.

And I cannot find a satisfying way to resolve this.

In the end, I would like to have something that looks like this (or similar) :

```js
type StoryDataType = {
    _id: string;
    ...;
} & DetailedMetric("firstPageVisible")<number> &
    DetailedMetric("metric2")<number> &
    DetailedMetric("metric3")<number> &
    DetailedMetric("metric4")<number> &
    ...;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `DetailedMetrics` like this:

```js
type DetailedMetric<Type, Name extends string> =  {
    [K in `${Name}Metrics`]?: Type 
} & {
    [K in `${Name}Count`]?: number 
} & {
    [K in `${Name}MetricsPerDevices`]?: PerDeviceData<Type> 
} & {
    [K in `${Name}CountPerDevices`]?: PerDeviceData<number> 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhwEMCWAbCATAsvATkgxgDwAq4EANFAHIIC20EAHsBAHboDOUHwerA5gD4oAXihQA3gChx4gNoBpKElZQABgBIJNegF9svAhzUBdAPwAuKKUhQpuqADJJM2YuWrN2uhF0BhAHsAV1ZgU0soViDaACMIHDsHZ2lZKHcVdS0dXwM8fA4ABXi4ADcCCGNzKyKcUvKYBEQSMmF7JxdU9M8sn39g0Jq6-Arw6uKIMuGGpqjY%20NbdKSXQW2IK4AAmUVh4ZDQsXAJCHj5%20SgAiBBj8c8EgA)

Answer (score 2):

You could map over a base type and use a relatively new TypeScript feature called [Key Remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) allowing you to compute a property key as you are trying to do`.

```js
type Base<T> = {
    Metrics?: T;
    Count?: number;
    MetricsPerDevices?: number;
    CountPerDevices?: number;
}

type DetailedMetric<Type> = <N extends string>(
    name: N,
) => {
    // Remap the name to be our generic `N`.
    [Key in keyof Base<Type> as `${N}${Key}`]: Base<Type>[Key];
};
```

This way you can define new properties in our `Base` type and have them automatically carried over.

[Here's a playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgHgCoD4oF4oG8BQURUAshMAE4CWAxggPwBcUqA3IcQMID2ArgHbAmUfrwC2AIwgV2xUuWp0ACtIAiEAG60IDZqMnTZXPoJUV1WmjuH6pM-AF98+UJCjrgcKgBsIAEzJKWjRwCEwcZAA5KAgAD2AIfj8EKAQg-gBzdAAKDiJ+ODEIZkiAGnwASmxMAjkAbQBpCBAoKn4oAGtm7gAzWEQUVFDMRCgAAwASXEiHKaaQBzGAXWZ4JBDIdEbmpfYHdmc-CBpvOApoGm5+NKgKZg8vXwCFYNwxEGYAclcIT9KoAAW0mKUE+l243k+DnQB0u12Atx0vG8CJwFGynwePn8nwq7AA9Pi5AA9ej4IA)